# How to implement iterator trait over wrapped vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

Having code like

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct BinaryVec {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}

impl BinaryVec {
    fn empty() -> BinaryVec {
        BinaryVec { vec: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, bit: u8) {
        self.vec.push(bit);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to iterate over the structure's vector without making it public. For example, to call it like:

```rust
let bin_vec = BinaryVec::empty();
bin_vec.push(1);
bin_vec.push(0);
bin_vec.push(1);
for el in bin_vec.iter() { 
    // do something with 1,0,1 elements 
}
```

But I see that `Iterator` trait requires only `next` method which assumes the saved iter state in the structure.

Is there any way to directly pass vec iter through the higher level struct in Rust without adding new state related fields to the struct?

Comment: `Vec<T>` itself is not an `Iterator`. It only implements `IntoIterator`. Perhaps you want to implement `IntoIterator` for your type instead (and also for `&BinaryVec` and `&mut BinaryVec`)?

Comment: Well, yes, looks like `IntoIterator` is the right trait to look for, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vec<T>` itself does not implement `Iterator` either. However, it implements `IntoIterator` in three ways:

- `impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T>`: you can write `for item in vec`, and each `item` will take a `T` by value. This consumes the vector.
- `impl<T> IntoIterator for &'_ [T]` (where `&Vec<T>` derefs to `&[T]`): you can write `for item in &vec`, and each `item` will take a `&T`.
- `impl<T> IntoIterator for &'_ mut [T]` (where `&mut Vec<T>` derefs to `&mut [T]`): you can write `for item in &mut vec`, and each `item` will take a `&mut T`.

You probably wanted to implement these for your wrapper as well:

```rust
impl IntoIterator for BinaryVec {
  type Item = u8;
  type IntoIter = <Vec<u8> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter; // so that you don't have to write std::vec::IntoIter, which nobody remembers anyway

  fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
    self.vec.into_iter()
  }
}

// We deref to slice so that we can reuse the slice impls
impl Deref for BinaryVec {
  type Output = [u8];

  fn deref(&self) -> &[u8] {
    &self.vec[..]
  }
}
impl DerefMut for BinaryVec {
  type Output = [u8];

  fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
    &mut self.vec[..]
  }
}
```

Note that implementing `IntoIterator` for `&mut [T]` is not trivial (you need to use stuff methods `split_first_mut` if you don't want to write unsafe code), so better reuse the implementation from slices.

Comment: Note that `Vec` also has `iter()` and `iter_mut()` methods.

Comment: Implementig `IntoIterator` for `&mut [T]` will not be easier if `T: Copy`, it's hardness is because it needs to use unsafe to bypass borrowck.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you're right, somehow I didn't realize it's returning `&mut T` instead of `T`. `&mut T` does not implement `Copy` even if `T: Copy`. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, to call it as you described, you don't need to implement `Iterator` for it.
You just need to return the iterator of the inner vec:

```
impl BinaryVec {
     ...
     fn iter(self: &Self) -> impl Iterator<Item=u8>{
           self.vec.iter()
     }
}
```

Note that even the standard `Vec` doesn't implement `Iterator`, It's the struct that `iter` returns that implements it.